# Dynamic array of static arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want a program that creates an undetermined amount of lists. The size of each list is fixed, but I can't determine at compile time how many lists am I going to need.

I understand I cannot create a vector of arrays. I also understand I can use a vector of vectors, but I wonder if this is the best efficient way to do it considering the fact I need to reserve a fixed amount of memory each time I need a new array.

Comment: Fixed-length and static are not the same thing.

Comment: Ahm... But fixed length allows you to create static arrays, and non-fixed does not, Does it?

Comment: You should wrap your list data type in a class of its own, *and* use `std::array` as its underlying storage. If you can't use C++11, you are probably better off using vectors rather than legacy C arrays. Any performance loss will probably be utterly insignificant.

Comment: All static arrays are fixed-length, but not all fixed-length arrays are static. *Your* arrays are not static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm, you can use a *vector of arrays*, for example,

```
std::vector<std::array<T, N>> some_vec;
```

Comment: That solved my question. Will vector `<array<array<int,2>, 64>>` create a vector of a 2x64 elements?

Comment: @D1X yes, it is declaring  a vector of arrays of size 64 where each array entry is an array of two ints, if that's what you are after..

Comment: And one more question: Let's suppose I have declared `vector<array<array<short,2>,64>> sol` and I want to copy the stack `stack<array<short,2> lifo` to the first element in vector _sol_. Is this correct?  `sol[0]=lifo;`

Comment: It should be `std::vector<std::array<T, N> > some_vec;` (note the space between the two `>`), otherwise the compiler will complain about invalid use of the `>>` operator.

Comment: @luator, `std::array` implies c++11, which means that you no longer need spaces between the angle brackets! You should upgrade your compiler (or standard!)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that this annoying problem was solved in C++11. Good to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

@Nim is right, but I cannot upvote yet :p
Also his solution is C++11.

Another alternative which is to be preferred over `std::vector<std::vector<T> >` is to have one vector with the dimensions X * Y. Then you can access your elements with v[y * Y + x];

This works with all versions of C++ and should be just as efficient as the `std::vector<std::array<T, N> >` solution.

Comment: if boost is already used, then yes. but I would not require boost just for that ;-) but yeah, boost is cool :-)